# Laravel Redis read error on connection to 127.0.0.1:6379

Tags: redis, laravel-artisan

Testing Redis pub/sub in my Laravel app. Executing this artisan command

```
public function callback(){
    print_r(func_get_args());
}

public function handle(): int
{
    $client = Redis::connection()->client();

    if($client->isConnected()){
        $this->line('Connected'); // Prints "Connected"
    }

    $client->subscribe(['exchanges'], [$this, 'callback']);
    $client->publish('exchanges', json_encode($this->getExchanges()));
 
    return 0;
}
```

gives this error:

```
read error on connection to 127.0.0.1:6379

  at app/Console/Commands/Client/Start.php:49
     45▕         if($client->isConnected()){
     46▕             $this->line('Connected');
     47▕         }
     48▕
  ➜  49▕         $client->subscribe(['exchanges'], [$this, 'callback']);
     50▕         $client->publish('exchanges', json_encode($this->getExchanges()));
     51▕
     52▕         return 0;
     53▕

  1   app/Console/Commands/Client/Start.php:49
      Redis::subscribe()
```

Whats wrong with subscribe() method?

Comment: Found this thread on github https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/issues/70. Same problem, related to phpredis. Proposed solution ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 0) however didn't help :(

Answer (score 3):

ini_set('default_socket_timeout', -1) Works for me.